# "hibernate.connection.provider_class" + multitenant for hibernate search integration

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, hibernate-search, hibernate-4.x

We use "hibernate.connection.provider_class" in multitenant connection with hibernate 4.0 and we try to integrate hibernate search 4.1.1.Final for our application, But the problem is when we try to purge all of the database, we can not get the session with the exact tenantid with this code " FullTextSession fullTextSession = org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(hibernateManagement.getHibernateSession());"

because ""hibernateManagement.getHibernateSession()" does not go call the "connection.provider_class" to get the exact session with tenant id so we purge all the provider instead of the client database

So there is any to get the session with the tenantid by passing through the "hibernate.connection.provider_class" because we cannot integrate such code ?

DATABASE
 factory.MultiTenantIdentifierResolver 
factory.MultiTenantConnectionProvider 
because it has a lot of influence in the rest of the application.

So Can we do this by getting the session of this property "" to build the 
FullTextSession?
our   com.application.resources.controller.ConnectionProvider  connection method is :

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
 try {


        String tenantId = null;


    Connection connection;
      GestionAffichageBean gestionAffichageBean=null;
   String host="";
  boolean distantConnection =false;


  if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() != null) {


   HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);


            if (session != null && session.getAttribute("tenantId") != null) {


   tenantId = (String) session.getAttribute("tenantId");
   }
  } else if (InjectionService.getBeanManager() != null) {
  if(gestionAffichageBean==null) {
  gestionAffichageBean = (GestionAffichageBean) InjectionService.getBeanByName("gestionaffichage");
   }

   tenantId = gestionAffichageBean.getTenantId();
  } else {
   tenantId = AppUtil.threadTenantId.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }


  if (gestionAffichageBean!=null && InjectionService.getBeanManager() != null){

  distantConnection=gestionAffichageBean.isDistantConnection();
  if(gestionAffichageBean.getHostIP()!=null)
  host=gestionAffichageBean.getHostIP();

   }

   if(distantConnection && !host.equals("") && !(host.equals("localhost")|| host.equals("127.0.0.1"))  ){


   System.out.println("getConnection() distantConnection => " + tenantId);


   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Properties prop = new Properties();


   String jdbcUrl;


   prop.put("user", "");
    prop.put("password", "");
  jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/";


   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, prop);
    connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);


     }else{
   javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/" + dataSourceNameDefault);
   connection = ds.getConnection();
    }



   if (tenantId != null) {
   connection.setCatalog(tenantId);
  }

   tenantId = null;

  return connection;



  } catch (Exception e) {
  throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
   }
   }
```